# I am getting console error during soap call using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting this error when I am trying to imitate a `SOAP` call using `AJAX`

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

My `AJAX` call is looking like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>getStatus/index',
    data: {devices: deviceString},
    success: function(data) {

         var obj = JSON.parse(data);


});
```

In my controller :

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com:8080/app/app?WSDL");
  $result=$client->getStatus($para);
  $array = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```

so anyone has what could be the reason getting this error?

Comment: If AJAX code is in JS file, it can't be read by PHP parser. Try with hard coded `url`. Why do you decode encoded array?

Comment: solved the problem  by just adding single quotation  data: {'devices': deviceString},

Answer (score 0):

Disable the CSRF or post the CSRF token with your data

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `dataType` parameter while initializing your ajax call, which will tell the jquery ajax call that what type of data is expected in response, by default it expects json if you dont mention it.

```
$.ajax({
    data: {devices: deviceString}, // what you are sending
    dataType: 'html', // what you are expecting
```